# SQL, выборка числовых значений аналогично оператору LIKE

Tags: sql, like

подскажите пожалуйста, существует ли механизм в SQL для поиска числовых значений, аналогичный оператору like?
Условно, если мне необходимо найти значения начинающиеся на "С", для текстовых значений это просто:
select * from where table like 'С%'

Север
Сырок
Плазма
Картон

А если у меня числовые значения и мне так же надо провести выборку аналогичную примеру выше?
Условно найти все значения, которые начинаются на 22 (2232 и 2244).

2232
2244
3411
2444

Comment: чем не устраивает такой вариант: select * from mytable where myfield like '22%'

Comment: Ещё один вариант-больше или равно 2200 и меньше или равно 2299

Comment: Преобразовать число в строку, а дальше вы знаете как. По последним цифрам можно было бы проверять остаток от деления на 100, а по первым проще через строку, чем математически.